# Flutter check if Uint8List is valid Image

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I've got a List of Cards which contain images. These images are picked by the user using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker). I first check if the image is not null and then read the bytes of it. After that I a Card containing an Image.memory to the list. My problem is that when the user picks a corrupted image (simulated by renaming an .exe to .png) the Card still get's displayed. I am looking for a solution where I can validate the Uint8List before adding the Card to the list.

###### Here's my code:

```dart
try {
  final XFile? pickedFile =
      await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  final data = await pickedFile?.readAsBytes();

  // a way to validate the data beforehand
  // and to make sure the Image will load correctly

  if (data != null) {
    setState(() {
      media.add(Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        child: Image.memory(
          data,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          errorBuilder: (context, error, stacktrace) {
            return const Text("An error happened here!");
          },
        ),
      ));
    });
  }
} catch (e) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.fixed,
      content: Text("An error occured! $e"),
    ),
  );
}
```

I've tried to wrap the `Image.memory` in a `Builder` and then call `.build()` on that, however that didn't throw an Error. I've also tried calling `Image.memory(...).image.resolve()` to see if that would throw an Error however it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the image, if successful, it is a valid image

```
Future<bool> isImageValid(List<int> rawList) async {
  final uInt8List =
      rawList is Uint8List ? rawList : Uint8List.fromList(rawList);

  try {
    final codec = await instantiateImageCodec(uInt8List, targetWidth: 32);
    final frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return frameInfo.image.width > 0;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited the answer, I doubt there is a better approach